# My codeigniter uploads images but not Json

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload

I can successfully upload images to my codeigniter controller:

```
class Upload extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->database();
    }

    function do_upload($folder)
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = './userdata/'. $folder . '/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|txt';
        $config['max_size'] = '1000';
        $config['max_width']  = '5024';
        $config['max_height']  = '5768';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); 
            echo $this->upload->display_errors();
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        }
    }
}
```

The images are uploaded from my JS like so:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('userfile', this.image);
$.ajax({
    url: 'upload/do_upload/atlas',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){

    }
});
```

Where `this.image` is the image file. Now this works fine so I know my controller and code works.

But when I try the same with a JSON string, the file is not uploaded:

```
this.json = JSON.stringify(parsedJSON, null, 4);

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('userfile', this.json);
$.ajax({
    url: 'upload/do_upload/json',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){

    }
});
```

Does anyone know why this works with images but not a Json string?

Answer (score 0):

You can use standart process for sending json data to server

```
var json = JSON.stringify(parsedJSON, null, 4);

$.ajax({
    url: 'upload/do_upload/json',
    data: json,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){

    }
});
```

Comment: This is basically what I am doing. When I do this I get the message: XHR finished loading: "http://localhost/development/editor/index.php/upload/do_upload/json".  But nothing is uploaded to the json folder

Comment: What you see in firebug or chrome development tools - any messages, errors, what request and response.